# Query using CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql, sql-update, case-when

I am trying to write a query like this and I am getting an error. It is my first time using case, so that's where I believe the problem to be.

```
UPDATE my_table 
       CASE
              WHEN downloads IS NULL THEN 
              SET    downloads = 1 
              ELSE 
              SET    downloads + 1 
       END
WHERE  attachment_id = 8990 
AND    parent_post_id = 9221 
OR     attachment_id = 9211 
AND    parent_post_id = 383
```

Comment: Back it up a bit. A CASE expression returns a value. You can use a CASE expression where you'd use an expression in a statement, like where a column name would go. You could do something along the lines of this **`UPDATE t SET t.col = CASE WHEN t.col IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE t.col + 1 END WHERE ...`**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can rewrite it as below

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET downloads = CASE WHEN downloads IS NULL THEN  1 
                ELSE downloads + 1 END
WHERE attachment_id = 8990 
AND (parent_post_id = 9221 
OR attachment_id = 9211 )
AND parent_post_id = 383
```

Also you need to group your `or` condition in `()` in order to match `9211` against `parent_post_id` and `attachment_id` with or operation,also there is  confusing conditions you have in your query how `parent_post_id` and `attachment_id` can be equal to 2 values at same time may be you are looking for

```
WHERE (attachment_id = 8990  AND parent_post_id = 9221 ) 
OR (attachment_id = 9211  AND parent_post_id = 383)
```

Answer (score 1):

`update`s syntax is `update table set col=value where condition`. Using `case` doesn't change that. `case` can only be used to return an expression, so:

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET    downloads = CASE WHEN downloads IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE downloads + 1 END 
WHERE  attachment_id = 8990 AND
       parent_post_id = 9221 OR
       attachment_id = 9211 AND 
       parent_post_id = 383
```